# How can I make a simple encryption of adding a value to the alphabet?

Tags: java, methods, unicode, char, range

I want to make a program that makes the letter `‘A’ to ‘B’`, and `‘Z’ to ‘A’`.
Basically a simple way to encrypt a message by increasing the Unicode value.

How can I make it, so that my program has a range of the Unicode value of `‘A’ to ‘Z’` so that when I want to encrypt or decrypt it, it only has the alphabet?

Comment: Post your existing code?

Comment: I haven’t started because I was thinking of using an if() statement but I thought it was inefficient. I saw a video on YouTube talking about range. How do I make this range? Ex. Unicode integer value of 68 - 98. Then looping from 68 when it goes over 98.

Comment: VTC as unattempted homework.

Comment: Get the code, increment it by one, check some special cases, convert it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if it's just `A-Z` that you care about, you can write a simple encryption function like so:

```
char encrypt(char letter){
    char[] alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
    char next_letter = alphabet[(letter - 'A' + 1) % 26];
    return next_letter;
}
```

`letter - 'A'` gives us the position of the letter in the alphabet array, for example if we wanted to get the position of 'C', `'C' - 'A' = 2` and the position of `alphabet[2]` is indeed 'C'.

To get the next letter, we offset by 1, ie `letter - 'A' + 1`

The `% 26` helps ensure we loop back to the beginning if we're at the end, ie when we're trying to encrypt 'Z' for example, 
'Z' - 'A' + 1 = 26
26 % 26 = 0.

```
System.out.println(encrypt('Z'));
>>> A
```

Likewise, you could write a decrypt function like so:

```
char decrypt(char letter){
    char[] alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
    char prev_letter = alphabet[26 - (letter - 'A' + 1)];
    return prev_letter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete @Ayush with the python version:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

def encrypt(letter):
    return ascii_uppercase[(ascii_uppercase.index(letter) + 1) % 26]

def decrypt(letter):
    return ascii_uppercase[(ascii_uppercase.index(letter) - 1) % 26]
```

Of course you have to make sure `letter` is an uppercase letter.